# Does writing custom sql increases size of tde?

Tags: tableau-api

Does writing custom sql increases size of tde?
i  am working on tableau. I have observed that when i used custom sql instead of including table directly, size of tde has been increased drastically.
Is is because of custom sql or there can be any other reason.?

Comment: Does your custom SQL produce the identical data that including the table directly does?

Comment: are you creating extracts? If you are just connecting live to tables custom SQL should not make a significant difference to the .tde size.

Answer (score 0):

Though i have not faced this issue, i think you can have a look at this link which might help you to consider while creating an extract.

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/tips-working-with-extracts